# Ruby on Rails: Creating a model with multiple data sources

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, redis

Right now my Rails app is configured to use MySQL. But suppose I want to create a new model and store it in Redis as well as MySQL. I know there is a way to have more than 1 data source in database.yml, but is there a way to map a model to multiple data sources? So when I create an instance of the model, the model gets inserted into both MySQL and redis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use callbacks, such as:

after_commit :saveToRedis, :on_create